# how to avoid Type of expression is ambiguous without more context when using closures in swift 4

Tags: swift

```
init(sceneView: ARSCNView,updateMotionData:(_ data: CMAccelerometerData?,_ error:Error?)->()){
```

..
..
 motionManager!.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: .main, withHandler: updateMotionData)

getting
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

suggestions?

Comment: Is there some static variable `ARSCNView.main` defined?

Answer (score 0):

When I get this error, I first start adding type annotations to every variable. If you do this to enough of the variables, you will then get a different error that will give you more information about what you are doing wrong. Chances are, you one of your types are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, you're missing `@escaping` on your `updateMotionData` parameter. I would also start by making it more explicitly what you need for this call:

```
init(sceneView: ARSCNView, updateMotionData: @escaping CMAccelerometerHandler)
```